# Finding the ratio of the circumference to the diameter.

Tags: geometry

What is the ratio of the circumference to the diameter if the circumference is 38 and the diameter is 12?

To get the ratio do I just divide 38 and 12 or is there something more to it?

Answer (score 1):

> The number $π$ is a mathematical constant, the **ratio of a circle's
>   circumference to its diameter**, commonly approximated as $3.14159$.

One way of approximating $\pi$ is by measuring circumference and corresponding diameter of every day objects.

In your case

$$\pi \approx 38 \div 12 = 3.1(6)$$